# "Mobile First" for developers definition

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

First - I understand what "Mobile First" means when it comes to **designing** websites.

At the company I work for, some of the developers are claiming that "Mobile First" in development means to write the mobile styles at the top of a CSS file then having desktop CSS override it via media queries instead of the other way around.

They claim this is the way to do it **AND** it will cut down on loading times in a mobile environment.

Does anyone have a definition on Mobile First for Development?  Can anyone prove that writing the mobile style sheet before the desktop stylesheet (with the intent to have desktop override mobile) will improve loading times?

Comment: In a classic debate scenario, the burden of proof is on the person making the claim.  If they can't *measure* the performance improvement then it's not a very strong claim.  (Not denying their claim here, I honestly don't know.  I'm just dubious about the validity of something taken as gospel without the numbers to back it up.)

Comment: @David, Unfortunately, I am dubious to their claims as well, though they refuse to do anything unless written in their specific way - even though they haven't ever written responsive before...

Comment: Mobile First has nothing to do with code order, or even code at all.  It's about how much stuff.   The best way I've heard it explained goes like- "It's easier to fill a mansion with stuff from an apartment than to figure out how to fit all the stuff from a mansion in an apartment."   It's easier to get stuff on the walls later, then it is to trip over stacks and stacks of boxes.

Comment: @ntgCleaner: In that case this isn't a technical challenge, it's a political challenge.  And get used to those :)  This reminds me of a quote I saw on Twitter... "Do software developers have superstitions?"  "Yes, we call them 'best practices'."

Comment: @briansol I absolutely agree and have read that analogy before.  I'm wondering if there's a way to make the developers aware that mobile first does not concern them in the way they think.

Comment: @david, Ha! Thank you.  I will have to use that - and yes, it seems political for sure.  Unfortunately, I don't have the time or the want to fight that battle without proof - so hopefully Austin's answer below (javascript needed) will dissuade them.  They don't like to use javascript that isn't theres.  It has to go through a stringent audit

Comment: I'm pretty sure coding your mobile styles first then creating media queries for desktops doesn't make that much of a difference in terms of performance (because the entire style sheet gets downloaded regardless?). If anything, it makes responsive design harder because it's a lot easier to collapse a structure than to build new walls and floors...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly how it has been explained to me before. There is a huge downside with this method though: IE8 and down do not support media queries, making your site look horrible. I use [this workaround](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) for those cases. You would just put that JS file inside of an IE8 statement.

I personally do not think this method matters that much. I believe that mobile-first is correct for design though since it will help show what is the most important in its most basic state.

Comment: That's a great point you add, Austin.  That might be the ticket to develop this stuff 'normally'.

Comment: Why don't we go for responsive designs rather than mobile first or other way around?

Comment: @Cherry, That's what I've been preaching for at least a year now with this company.  It should just be designed correctly, not designed for one over the other.

Comment: @ntgCleaner I've been doing mobile first web design since 2011, which a long time in Internet time and it's better for the end user because you are not loading the styles for large devices to small devices. Just a small example is that I load up small background images and then they get larger as the media queries go up in the min-width. I've used respond.js and the other media-queries.js to support IE 8 for clients who only have ie8 and can't upgrade (at that time) it has been fine. Don't do crazy design and js stuff (or hide the script if (!$('html').hasClass('ie8')) {...}.

Comment: @ntgCleaner but also I will use server side detection to serve up html specifically for small devices and why would I also serve them the desktop slider that I'm not even using for them and the images too? That's mean. So adaptive, mobile first, responsive design is what is best for users and it's easier.